# python azure check if blob is saved to archive

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to know if there exist a method to check if a blob(task) is successfully saved within azure and if there was a way to get returned something if save was successful.
The current code I have uploads to azure using blobserviceclient, and what I am trying to do is deleting tasks that was uploaded in azure and not deleting the ones that were was not saved in archive.

what I have tried to implement is this, however by doing so it checks if the file exist within azure instead of checking and getting returned something if upload was successful within azure.

```
async def if_uploaded(works):

    container_name = "works"

    try:
        block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey,
                                                socket_timeout=10000)
        isExist = block_blob_service.exists(container_name, filename)
        if isExist:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The code for upload is

```
async def upload(works):
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there exist a method to check if a blob(task)
> is successfully saved within azure and if there was a way to get
> returned something if save was successful.

If you do not get any error while uploading that would mean the blob got uploaded successfully. You don't really need to do anything else to check if the upload operation was successful or not.

To check if the blob upload was successful, just wrap your upload code in try/except block. Something like:

```
try:
  await upload_file(blob_service_client, container_name, file_name, content)
  # blob upload successful...do something here...
except:
  # blob upload failed...do something here...
  print("An exception occurred")
```

Comment: what line would I use to see if upload was successfull? The reason being, I'm trying to create a code that deletes those that were sucessful but not the ones that were not uploaded successfully.

Comment: That would be in your upload code which you have not shared. Please edit your question and include the code which uploads the blobs.